# 2 Cookies with different domain made in Atlassian Crowd + IIS(ARR) proxy

Tags: cookies, atlassian-crowd

There are 3 servers, IIS(WEB), JIRA and Crowd.

Users can access to JIRA with IIS proxy(ARR) like `http://xxx.yyy.zzz.com/jira`.

A problem is that WEB(IIS) server makes Crowd cookie as *.yyy.zzz.com and JIRA makes it as xxx.yyy.zzz.com. Some users can not login Jira when a cookie as xxx.yyy.zzz.com exists, crashing other cookie as *.yyy.zzz.com.

I want to let JIRA make cookie as *.yyy.zzz.com to avoid making two different cookies.